# CFChart not displaying all chart data items

Tags: flash, coldfusion, charts

I am having an issue with ColdFusion's CFChart tag. I have a couple graphs that do not display properly. For a horizontal bar chart, when attempting to display 50 or more chart data items, the graph's bar labels stop plotting, but keeps plotting the bars themselves once it gets to bar number 50. I noticed making the chart height larger makes the issue worse as well. If i go from 1000px pixels to 2000px, it stopped plotting labels even sooner. The query that populates the chart items do not return blank label names either. See the screen below, the labels should keep plotting after "7 to 1".

[alt text http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1267118593090012000.png](http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1267118593090012000.png)

I am running on ColdFusion 8 Developer Edition. Is this a possible limitation for ColdFusion's native charting capabilities? Or should I consider checking out Flex Charting instead?

Thank you!

CF Code:

```
<cfset hideZeroData = "25">
<cfparam name="paramID" default="25">

<cfset ecfData = QueryNew("ecfName,cumValue")>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 1 to 2",1)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "26", 1)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 1 to 3",2)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "19", 2)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 1 to 4",3)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "11", 3)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 1 to 5",4)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "14", 4)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 1 to 6",5)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "38", 5)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 1 to 7",6)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "24", 6)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 1 to N",7)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "14", 7)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 1 to R",8)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "24", 8)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 2 to 1",9)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "16", 9)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 2 to 3",10)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "32", 10)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 2 to 4",11)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "34", 11)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 2 to 5",12)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "30", 12)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 2 to 6",13)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "34", 13)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 2 to 7",14)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "25", 14)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 2 to N",15)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "30", 15)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 2 to R",16)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "15", 16)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 3 to 1",17)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "26", 17)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 3 to 2",18)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "46", 18)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 3 to 4",19)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "11", 19)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 3 to 5",20)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "26", 20)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 3 to 6",21)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "19", 21)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 3 to 7",22)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "16", 22)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 3 to N",23)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "28", 23)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 3 to R",24)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "13", 24)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 4 to 1",25)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "19", 25)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 4 to 2",26)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "13", 26)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 4 to 3",27)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "36", 27)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 4 to 5",28)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "22", 28)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 4 to 6",29)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "4", 29)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 4 to 7",30)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "17", 30)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 4 to N",31)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "24", 31)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 4 to R",32)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "12", 32)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 5 to 1",33)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "21", 33)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 5 to 2",34)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "28", 34)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 5 to 3",35)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "24", 35)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 5 to 4",36)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "37", 36)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 5 to 6",37)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "24", 37)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 5 to 7",38)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "12", 38)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 5 to N",39)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "24", 39)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 5 to R",40)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "19", 40)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 6 to 1",41)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "19", 41)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 6 to 2",42)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "20", 42)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 6 to 3",43)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "21", 43)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 6 to 4",44)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "16", 44)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 6 to 5",45)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "27", 45)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 6 to 7",46)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "6", 46)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 6 to N",47)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "24", 47)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 6 to R",48)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "25", 48)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 7 to 1",49)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "16", 49)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 7 to 2",50)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "16", 50)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 7 to 3",51)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "18", 51)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 7 to 4",52)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "13", 52)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 7 to 5",53)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "35", 53)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 7 to 6",54)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "17", 54)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 7 to N",55)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "13", 55)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - 7 to R",56)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "2", 56)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - Any gear to L",57)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "233", 57)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - Any gear to P",58)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "182", 58)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - N to 1",59)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "21", 59)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - N to 2",60)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "24", 60)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - N to 3",61)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "21", 61)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - N to 4",62)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "10", 62)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - N to 5",63)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "13", 63)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - N to 6",64)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "29", 64)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - N to 7",65)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "14", 65)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - N to R",66)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "22", 66)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - R  to 1",67)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "7", 67)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - R to  2",68)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "19", 68)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - R to 3",69)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "18", 69)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - R to 4",70)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "16", 70)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - R to 5",71)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "22", 71)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - R to 6",72)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "13", 72)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - R to 7",73)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "27", 73)>
<cfset temp = QueryAddRow(ecfData)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"ecfName", "Transmission Range - R to N",74)>
<cfset temp = QuerySetCell(ecfData,"cumValue", "10", 74)>

<cfoutput>
    <cfif ecfData.recordCount GT 0>
        <cfif ecfData.recordCount GT 10 AND ecfData.recordCount LT 50>
            <cfset chartStyle="DIME_events_thin">
            <cfset chartHeight = 1000>
        <cfelseif ecfData.recordCount GT 50>
            <cfset chartStyle="DIME_events_thin">
            <cfset chartHeight = 2500>  <!--- 1500px is the approximate max height that won't hide labels, after that labels start hiding. Except with 1500 px height, the labels get squished --->
        <cfelse>
            <cfset chartStyle="DIME_events_thin">
            <cfset chartHeight = 400>
        </cfif>

        <cfchart
            format="flash"
            xaxistitle=""           
            yaxistitle="Events"
            chartwidth="725" 
            fontSize="10"
            chartheight="#chartHeight#"
            style="#chartStyle#">
            <cfchartseries type="horizontalbar" seriescolor="##4AFF4A">
                <cfloop query="ecfData">
                    <cfif (NOT ListFind(hideZeroData, paramID)) OR (ecfData.cumValue GT 0)>
                        <cfchartdata item="#ListLast(ecfData.ecfName,'-')#" value="#ecfData.cumValue#">
                    </cfif>
                </cfloop>
            </cfchartseries>
        </cfchart>
    </cfif>
</cfoutput>
```

XML CF Chart Style Sheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<frameChart autoAdjust="false" is3D="false" isInterpolated="true">
    <frame xDepth="6" yDepth="6"  outline="#333333" lightColor="white" 
        leftAxisPlacement="Front" rightAxisPlacement="Front" stripColor="#CCCCCC"/>
    <xAxis isVisible="true" scaleMin="0" scaleMax="100">
        <labelStyle isHideOverlapped="false" orientation="Horizontal" />
        <titleStyle font="Arial-12-bold" isMultiline="false" />
    </xAxis>
    <yAxis scaleMin="0">
        <titleStyle font="Arial-12-bold" isMultiline="true" />
        <dateTimeStyle majorUnit="Year" minorUnit="Month"/>
        <labelFormat style="Pattern" pattern="#,##0.########"/>
    </yAxis>
    <yAxis2>
        <titleStyle font="Arial-12-bold"/>
    </yAxis2>
    <topYAxis>
        <titleStyle font="Arial-12-bold"/>
    </topYAxis>
    <topYAxis2>
        <titleStyle font="Arial-12-bold"/>
    </topYAxis2>
    <dataLabels foreground="black"/>
    <legend isVisible="false" showColumnLegend="true">
        <decoration style="None"/>
    </legend>
    <elements action="" shape="Area" drawOutline="false" shapeSize="20">
        <morph morph="Grow"/>
        <series index="0">
            <paint color="#E48701"/>
        </series>
        <series index="1">
            <paint color="#A5BC4E"/>
        </series>
        <series index="2">
            <paint color="#1B95D9"/>
        </series>
        <series index="3">
            <paint color="#CACA9E"/>
        </series>
        <series index="4">
            <paint color="#6693B0"/>
        </series>
        <series index="5">
            <paint color="#F05E27"/>
        </series>
        <series index="6">
            <paint color="#86D1E4"/>
        </series>
        <series index="7">
            <paint color="#E4F9A0"/>
        </series>
        <series index="8">
            <paint color="#FFD512"/>
        </series>
        <series index="9">
            <paint color="#75B000"/>
        </series>
        <series index="10">
            <paint color="#0662B0"/>
        </series>
        <series index="11">
            <paint color="#EDE8C6"/>
        </series>
        <series index="12">
            <paint color="#CC3300"/>
        </series>
        <series index="13">
            <paint color="#D1DFE7"/>
        </series>
        <series index="14">
            <paint color="#52D4CA"/>
        </series>
        <series index="15">
            <paint color="#C5E05D"/>
        </series>
        <series index="16">
            <paint color="#E7C174"/>
        </series>
        <series index="17">
            <paint color="#FFF797"/>
        </series>
        <series index="18">
            <paint color="#C5F68F"/>
        </series>
        <series index="19">
            <paint color="#BDF1E6"/>
        </series>
        <series index="20">
            <paint color="#9E987D"/>
        </series>
        <series index="21">
            <paint color="#EB988D"/>
        </series>
        <series index="22">
            <paint color="#91C9E5"/>
        </series>
        <series index="23">
            <paint color="#93DC4A"/>
        </series>
        <series index="24">
            <paint color="#FFB900"/>
        </series>
        <series index="25">
            <paint color="#9EBBCD"/>
        </series>
        <series index="26">
            <paint color="#009797"/>
        </series>
        <series index="27">
            <paint color="#0DB2C2"/>
        </series>
    </elements>
    <popup background="#C8FFFFFF" foreground="#333333"/>
    <paint paint="Plain"/>
    <insets left="5" top="5" right="5" bottom="5"/>
</frameChart>
```

Comment: can you post a snippet of your code?

Comment: It looks to be an error in your code. Please post it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The Code is up on the main post.

Comment: It may be helpful if you can "fake" the data (using queryNew) and share that. The gist is - get it to a point where we can run it ourselves and duplicate the issue.

Comment: @CF Jedi Master: Thank you for the suggestion, I'm a bit of a newb in CF and stackoverflow so I appreciate the tip.  I updated the code on the main post. It contains record set data. This the exact data that my chart code is displaying. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry - I banged away at this for a while, and couldn't get it to work. I tried recreating the issue in the Chart Editor. I modified the default data to have more than 50 columns but I was unable to reproduce the issue. I therefore thought it was your style. I noticed htat this line:

labelStyle isHideOverlapped="false" orientation="Horizontal" isMultilevel="true"

Was the main culprit. You remove it and you saw all the labels - but they were hard to read because of their orientation.

Ahah - try this:

labelStyle isMultilevel="true"

It isn't oriented right, but seems to work.

Comment: You mean isMultiLevel="false"? :D Thank you! Yeah that isMultiLevel is the one that screwed me over. Setting it to false took care of my problems with the labels. Sorry for the long wait for response, I forgot to come back and confirm the fix.